# How to use CASE in a SELECT statement with CONCAT

Tags: sql-server, case

I'm trying to use a CASE statement in a SELECT statement with CONCAT but getting invalid expression with the last AS statement

I've tried placing the CASE statement inside the CONCAT and placing END before the final AS but still can't get this to work.

```
SELECT USER_ID AS [USER_ID], USER_TITLE AS [USER_TITLE], (CASE USER.Active   
WHEN 'N' THEN '' ELSE 
concat('http://www.mywebsite.com/','folder/',USER.NAME,'.doc' ) AS [LINK]
```

The final result should be (if USER.Active is 'Y' then show the website link, else show nothing at all).

Comment: You're missing the final `end` from your code, and you don't need brackets around the `case`.

Comment: Your CASE needs an END.

Comment: Not part of the problem but you don't need to use column aliases if you are just using the same name. All that does is make you type more.

Comment: You also need to square bracket keyword `USER` e.g. `[USER]`

Comment: Why would there be down votes to this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the `END`

```
SELECT USER_ID AS [USER_ID], USER_TITLE AS [USER_TITLE], (CASE USER.Active   
WHEN 'N' THEN '' ELSE 
concat('http://www.mywebsite.com/','folder/',USER.NAME,'.doc') END) AS [LINK]
```

Comment: I had tried END but the issue was that I forgot the parentheses after the END. Thank you.